# Test Execution Error in Lambda RDS Data API for Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-rds-data-service

I am trying to connect the AWS Lambda with SQL query to an AWS RDS (MySQL) using the Data API and return the query result for a user with a particular `id`.

This is how the **handler** looks like:

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const RDS = new AWS.RDSDataService({ endpoint: '******.cluster-*********.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' })
    
module.exports.fetchById = async (event, context, callback) => {

  const req_id = event.pathParameters.id;

  try {
    const params = {
      resourceArn: 'arn:aws:rds:us-west-2:***********',
      secretArn: 'arn:aws:secretsmanager********',
      sql: `SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = :id`,
      database: '*********',
      includeResultMetadata: true,
      parameters: [
        { id: req_id },
      ]
    }

    const db_res = await rdsDataService.executeStatement(params).promise();

    const response = {
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'Data fetched!!',
        data: db_res.records
      })
    };
    callback(null, response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error Received', error)
  }
};
```

**serverless.yml**

```
functions:
  fetchByIdId:
    handler: handler.fetchById
    events:
      - http:
          path: user/{id}
          method: get
          authorizer:
            name: cognito-authorizer
            arn: arn:aws:***********
          request:
            parameters:
              paths:
                id: true
```

Few issues that I need to work upon:

1. If I instantiate like:

   `const RDS = new AWS.RDSDataService({ endpoint: '******.cluster-*********.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' })`

by including an endpoint cluster as a parameter, the handler function does not execute at all. It just keeps throwing:

`{"errorMessage": "2020-10-30T07:31:12.258Z c4b4ca2d-3cbb-4733-8cfe-0c7aad228c29 Task timed out after 6.01 seconds"}`.

Tried increasing the timeout also but it didn't made any difference & the error still perists.
But if endpoint is removed & only used like:

```
const RDS = new AWS.RDSDataService()
```

, the function does not throw timeout error, but these two new issues are faced:

1. The `id` is required. I passed the required config to the yml file, but it
   doesn't seem to mark it as required. If the http endpoint is executed as
   `/user/`, it does not throw any error.
2. I need to perform input data validation/sanitization for the request
   parameters. On executing the endpoint `/user/123`, it throws an error:
   `INFO Error Received UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'id' found in  params.parameters[0]`.

I read out in the documentation but could not find any particular clue to complete the same.

Any help to resolve this is appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are using Aurora Serverless?

Comment: @Marcin. Yea. I am using Aurora serverless

Comment: Is your lambda in a VPC?